# How the domain name and IP get mapped?

Tags: ip, subdomain, appdomain

Suppose xx.xx.xx.xx is the ip address of www.yyyy.com then the server can be accessed by http://xx.xx.xx.xx:port/.
How and where www.yyyy.com get mapped to http://xx.xx.xx.xx:port/ ?

Answer (score 0):

The Mapping is done by DNS(Domain Name Server). You can read more [here](http://computer.howstuffworks.com/web-server7.htm) .

Edit:

Check [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/208172/how-does-my-browser-know-where-to-get-data-from-a-server) for more info.

Comment: The article is informative to some extent. I want to know the detailed ans. When we give www.facebook.com to browser send the request to the DNS server. So how the browser get details of the DNS server?